# Angular - how to make angular object to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an object in angular that looks like this:

```
quiz.js:129 m {$promise: Promise, $resolved: false}
   439:"https://mysite.no/sites/default/files/styles/quiz_large/public/fields/question-image/istock_000059790188_large.jpg?itok=62PzCown"
   679: ""
   1379:"https://mysite.no/sites/default/files/styles/quiz_large/public/fields/question-image/istock_000000301688_medium.jpg?itok=poGpHb5c"
   1529:"https://mysite.no/sites/default/files/styles/quiz_large/public/fields/question-image/istock_000011483027_large.jpg?itok=LJ3f0c-X"
   2022:"https://www.mysite.no/sites/default/files/styles/quiz_large/public/fields/question-image/208458_thumbnail.jpg?itok=6AG_2XS3"
   $promise: Promise
   $resolved: true__proto__: Object
```

I would need to make an array out of that data, but not sure how to make this.

Comment: add loop on your data and add one by one in one array

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more? I am not sure about the above given code is a reported exception or the desired object you want to convert to an array.

Comment: Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: see the object is having number of entries, so add loop on all entries and add in array one by one.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? This is one way of doing it, though the error your getting doesn't seem to point that this is the issue.

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj)
    .map(function(key) { return obj[key] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can lodash _.values(obj) this will creates an array of values of this object.

[Here](https://lodash.com/docs#values) is the documentation and here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/2690/) for the same.

I hope this helps, Thanks.

```
var obj = { 
     439:"https://mysite.no/sites/default/files/styles/quiz_large/public/fields/question-image/istock_000059790188_large.jpg?itok=62PzCown",
     679: "",
     1379:"https://mysite.no/sites/default/files/styles/quiz_large/public/fields/question-image/istock_000000301688_medium.jpg?itok=poGpHb5c",
     1529:"https://mysite.no/sites/default/files/styles/quiz_large/public/fields/question-image/istock_000011483027_large.jpg?itok=LJ3f0c-X",
     2022:"https://www.mysite.no/sites/default/files/styles/quiz_large/public/fields/question-image/208458_thumbnail.jpg?itok=6AG_2XS3"
    }
  console.log(_.values(obj));
```